# Codeigniter multiple query results in Session

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

im a begginer in programming. I want to simply check value of my int in SQL and save it to variable. It's not problem when it's one result. But when it's two results I got a problems.  Im sorry for my chaotic english. I hope you understand me

```
    $this->db->where('login', $login);
    $this->db->where('password', $password);
    $result = $this->db->get('users');
    $this->db->where('admin', 1);     // I want to get users who have admin as "1"
    $admin = $this->db->get('users'); // Admin result ???

    if($result->num_rows() > 0)
    {

        $user = array(
            'username'  => md5($login),
            'logged_in' => true,
            // Now i don't know how to check admin var is equal to 1. If 1 i want to add something like this:
            'admin' => true
        );

        $this->session->set_userdata($user);
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to make 2 queries to check if the user is an admin. Just check the results from the one row you selected:

```
    $this->db->where('login', $login);
    $this->db->where('password', $password);
    $query = $this->db->get('users');

    $row = $query->row();

    if (isset($row)) {
      $user = array(
        'username'  => md5($login),
        'logged_in' => true,
        'admin' => $row->admin //IF YOU HAVE 1 = ADMIN IN YOUR TABLE?
      );

      $this->session->set_userdata($user);
      return true;
    }
```

Alternative if you need to convert 1/0 to true/false:

```
 if (isset($row)) {
  $admin = ($row->admin == 1) ? true : false; // IF DB HAS INTEGER 1
  $user = array(
    'username'  => md5($login),
    'logged_in' => true,
    'admin' => $admin
  );

  $this->session->set_userdata($user);
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  for your help. Seems to be ok

Comment: Please accept the answer and upvote if it solved your problem in your first question. Instead of adding an answer with a completely different question i suggest you create a new question for your menu/session problem. It has nothing to do with the original question.